# Django Template Queryset Issue

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

So Im literally going crazy trying to understand why I can't retrieve an individual value from a dictionary that's being passed to my template.

```
def createCharacterSkills(request):
        
    user = request.user
      
    if user.is_authenticated and request.method=="GET":
        
        characterid = request.session["characterid"]
        print(characterid)
        
        characterrecord = character.objects.filter(pk=characterid)
        print(characterrecord.values())
            
        return render(request, "characters/createcharacter2.html", {'characterrecord':characterrecord})
```

Is what I am passing to my template. Below is the relevant code in my template:

```
                        <b>Name: </b>{{ characterrecord.values }} <br>
                        <b>Player Reference: </b>{{ characterrecord.id }}<br>
```

The characterrecord.values is working correctly and returning the whole dictionary as expected.

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 48, 'player_id': 1, 'character_name': 'Avalon', 'character_race': 'Dwarf', 'character_faction': 'Jhereg', 'character_group': 'Moredhel', 'ambidexterity': 0, 'dagger': 0, 'one_handed_weapon': 0, 'pole_arms': 0, 'projectile_weapons': 0, 'shield': 0, 'two_handed_weapons': 0, 'thrown_weapons': 0, 'wear_light_armour': 0, 'wear_medium_armour': 0, 'wear_heavy_armour': 0, 'wear_extra_heavy_armour': 0, 'body_development': 0, 'literacy': 0, 'surgeon': 0, 'numeracy': 0, 'alchemist': 0, 'crafting': 0, 'evaluate': 0, 'ranger_1': 0, 'ranger_2': 0, 'make_and_read_maps': 0, 'recongnise_forgery': 0, 'poison_lore_1': 0, 'posion_Lore_2': 0, 'potion_lore_1': 0, 'potion_lore_2': 0, 'ritual_contribute': 0, 'ritual_magic': 0, 'invocation': 0, 'corporeal_1': 0, 'corporeal_2': 0, 'mage_1': 0, 'mage_2': 0, 'shamanism_1': 0, 'shamanism_2': 0, 'forage': 0, 'meditation': 0, 'vet_ritual_magic': 0, 'vet_ritual_contribute': 0, 'chameleon': 0, 'fearless': 0, 'natural_armour': 0, 'sense_magic': 0, 'track': 0, 'intuition': 0, 'poison_resistance': 0, 'resist_magic': 0, 'sense_trap': 0, 'iron_will': 0, 'resist_disease': 0, 'discern_truth': 0, 'scrounge': 0, 'tricks_of_the_trade': 0, 'versatility': 0, 'regeneration': 0, 'extra_body_dev': 0}]>
```

However when I try to address and individual key in the dictionary I have no value in the template. I have done this numerous times in the past with no issue so I am at a loss as to why I am having this issue now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `querysets` you cannot access `querysets` data directly

```
{% for character_record in characterrecord %}
     <b>Name: </b>{{ character_record.character_name}} <br>
     <b>Player Reference: </b>{{ character_record.player.id}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had completely missed the fact that I was using object.filter so I would need to loop even with 1 record. I think its time to step away from keyboard for the day,

Comment: My pleasure @adamt. You are right for 1 record you don't have to pass `querysets` just return `instance`. And for single object @Willem Van Onsem sir has the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You here have a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, so in that case you should enumerate over the `QuerySet`.

But here you filter on the primary key, so you can obtain a single item:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def createCharacterSkills(request):
    characterrecord = get_object_or_404(character, pk=request.session['characterid'])
    return render(request, 'characters/createcharacter2.html', {'characterrecord': characterrecord})
```

there is no need to use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values): by using a model object, you do not erase the model layer.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: @adamt willem is right yet another way is like this: `character.objects.filter(pk=characterid).first()` that will give you None if no record found or the object that matched.